# ¿Por qué un div se completa de abajo hacia arriba?

Tags: css, web

Dentro de mi código, tengo la estructura de mi pagina dividida en tres `<div>`, `.encabezado`, `.cuerpo` y `.pie-pagina`, a su vez el cuerpo esta dividido en dos `<div>`, los cuales son : `columna.medio` y `columna.side`, el caso es que me centre en programar todo lo de la `columna.medio` descuidando la otra(`columna.side`), hace un momento quise agregar texto a esta ultima y noto que cada que agregaba un elemento(en este caso con el tag `<p>`) se completaba de abajo hacia arriba, probé hacer unos cambios en la hoja de estilo pero no resulto, aparte de mi código dejo un pequeño enlace con un vídeo para que se entienda mejor el problema. Aquí dicho  [Vídeo demostración del problema](https://streamable.com/b8op52). a continuación el html y css.
Añado una imagen de como se ve al colocar algo de contenido en la `columna.side`, todo lo que vaya colocando dentro de ese contenedor, se comienza a añadir hacia arriba, es extraño el comportamiento [Imagen de la columna](http://imgfz.com/i/UugDadq.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>OBSERVATORIO</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum- 
scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="estilos.css" TYPE="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="slider.js"></script>
<script src="menu_bar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="encabezado">
</div>
<div class="cuerpo">
<div class="columna medio">
</div>
<div class="columna side" >
</div>
</div>
<div class="pie-pagina">
<p>Pie de pagina</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

aquí el css

```
/* ------------------------ ESTRUCTURA GENERAL-------------------------------- */
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }
.encabezado {
width: 100%;
}
.columna.side {
 width: 19.64%;
 background-color:#aaa; 
 display: inline-block;

 }
 .columna.medio {
 width: 79.67%;  
  display: inline-block;
 }
 .pie-pagina {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
 }
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

Comment: Yo veo el video y no entiendo el problema, el texto que colocas se coloca al final, ¿puedes explicarte mejor?

Comment: el problema es que dicho texto no aparece a la derecha del slider y como bien se ve en el vídeo dentro de la columna.side ya existen 3 etiquetas <p> pero las mismas en lugar de mostrarse desde bien arriba(a la derecha del slider) me aparecen a la mitad de la pantalla y mientras siga colocando mas contenido a la columna.side, el contenedor se extiende hacia arriba y no hacia abajo como normalmente sucedería, nose si me explico?..Edite la pregunta para agregar la imagen de como se ve el contenedor cuando coloco solo un parrafo dentro. @BetaM

Comment: "<div class="columna side" > /div>" está mal escrito; te falta "<"

Comment: si ahí lo edite, eso fue un error de tipeo cuando coloque mi código acá en la pregunta, en mi archivo local lo tengo bien. de todas maneras gracias @Elboy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás usando display: inline-block para los contenedores, eso lo resuelves con:

```
.columna.side {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Aunque yo te recomendaría quitar el `inline-block` y alinear los contenedores con `flex`

```
.cuerpo {
    display: flex;
}
.columna.side {
    width: 19.64%;
    background-color:#aaa; 
}
.columna.medio {
    width: 79.67%;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ambos ejemplos me sirvieron y opté por tu recomendación, ya que me resulta mas practico, solo que tuve que volver a poner `display:inline-block` cuando hace reponsive en `@media (max-width: 700px)` , ya que con el `display:flex` no quedaba bien.. @Elboy

Comment: Ahora bien si no es mucha molestia me gustaría saber de forma sintáctica , ¿Por qué recomiendas justamente `display:flex` en lugar de  `display:inline-block`? , yo tenia entendido que el inline-block servia para generar bloques que puedan estar uno al lado del otro por mas que estén en la misma "linea". @Elboy

Comment: Un contendor hecho para funcionar como block, lo ideal es que sea block, inline-block se recomienda mas para cambiar la funcionalidad de un contenedor inline, y poder dar mas propiedades css. los contenedores block antes se posicionaban a la izquierda o derecha con `float: left;` o `float: right;` esto ha sido desplazado por flex y existen mas posibilidades de manipulación con respecto a los float.